# Symfony doctrine OneToAll relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to create a kind of "OneToAll" association with doctrine

I have 2 distinct entities which are not related. And I don't want them to be mapped with a ManyToMany association. 
The entities content a very large amount of entries and in this case I need to create entries in the join table for all the datas

Can I create a custom doctrine relation which join one entity to all entries of another entity? It will be something like:

```
/**
 * One entityA has All entityB.
 * @ORM\OneToAll(targetEntity="EntityB")
 */
private $entitiesB;
```

I have find this in the doctrine doc:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Is this can help me for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine does not naturally support this as - from a database mapping-standpoint - it would not make sense to load not associated objects whenever one column from table a is fetched. This could also have serious performance impacts.

From what it sounds like you should either treat both A and B separately or find a different solution to making changes to both A and B at the same time, e.g. by providing some kind of Facade or a service managing both entity's repositories. If you absolutely need this, one possible option is: adding another layer of abstraction by providing a class that contains both a single EntityA and all EntityB-objects

```
class EntityAWithBs
{
    private $a;
    private $bs;

    public function __construct(EntityA $a, array $allBs)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->bs = $allBs;
    }

    public function getEntityA(): EntityA
    {
        return $this->a;
    }

    public function getAllBs(): array
    {
        return $this->bs;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a class like a custom repository or add the following method to your EntityA-repository:

```
public function getAWithAllBs($id): EntityAWithBs
{
    $a = $this->entityManager->getRepository('EntityA')->find($id);
    $bs = $this->entityManager->getRepository('EntityB')->findAll();

    return new EntityAWithBs($a, $bs);
}
```

Whenever you need an Entity A with all Entity Bs at the same time you can just call the repository method. You can also expand this example to have a service that performs actions on the newly created `EntityAWithBs` like changing the data and then persisting it.

Please be aware, that this still has some of the initially remarked drawbacks such as possible performance issues, e.g. related to memory usage. Without any knowledge what you try to accomplish with this relation, this is the best I can come up with.